# Finding numerical derivative using fft and ifft of numpy

Tags: python, numpy, fft

I want to find the derivative of the function

`\begin{equation} f(t) = \sin(t)e^{−3t}, \end{equation}`

using fft and ifft and compare to the analytical derivative given by

`\begin{equation} f'(t) = \cos(t)e^{-3t} -3\sin(t)e^{-3t}, \end{equation}`

with a interval of [-1,1]

Can someone tell me what's wrong with it, cause my numerical Derivative is appearing as just a straight line.

This was my code:

```
N = 2000
T = 2
t = np.linspace(-T/2,T/2,N)                                     

f = np.sin(t)*np.exp(-3*t)
df = np.cos(t) * np.exp(-3*t) - 3 * np.sin(t) * np.exp(-3*t)


omega = 2*np.pi/T
Scale_factor = 1/(N * (t[1]-t[0]))

f_fft = np.fft.fft(f)/N
derivative_fft = np.fft.ifft(1j*omega*Scale_factor*f_fft)*N

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))

plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
plt.plot(t, f, label=r'$f(t)$')
plt.title(r'Function $f(t) = \sin(t) e^{-3t}$')

plt.subplot(2, 1, 2)
plt.plot(t, df , label='Analytical Derivative', linestyle='--')
plt.plot(t, np.real(derivative_fft), label='Numerical Derivative (FFT)', linestyle='--')
plt.title('Derivative Comparison')
plt.legend()

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/430885/414894 — your `omega` is a constant instead of the frequency variable it’s supposed to be. Try using `fftfreq()`.